# Dynamic Strategy Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

So I'm writing a web service architecture which includes `FunctionProvider` classes which do the actual processing of requests, and a main `Endpoint` class which receives and delegates requests to the proper `FunctionProvider`.

I don't know exactly the `FunctionProvider`s available at runtime, so I need to be able to 'register' (if that's the right word) them with my main `Endpoint` class, and query them to see if they match an incoming request.

```
public class MyFunc implements FunctionProvider{
  static {
    MyEndpoint.register(MyFunc);
  }
  public Boolean matchesRequest(Request req){...}
  public void processRequest(Request req){...}
}

public class MyEndpoint{
  private static ArrayList<FunctionProvider> functions = new ArrayList<FunctionProvider>();
  public void register(Class clz){
    functions.add(clz);
  }
  public void doPost(Request request){
    //find the FunctionProvider in functions
    //matching the request
  }
}
```

I've really not done much reflective Java like this (and the above is likely wrong, but hopefully demonstrates my intentions).

What's the nicest way to implement this without getting hacky?

Comment: This is probably better suited on SO as you are asking for an implementation answer. Good rule of thumb is if your question involves you being in front of your IDE then it belongs on SO. If you question has you in front a whiteboard it belongs on Programmers. Please don't reask your question there, a moderator can migrate it for you.

Answer (score 2):

- Do not let the FunctionProviders self register. Bootstrap the endpoint through some application init. call with a list of FunctionProviders. That way you can configure priority (what if two providers both claim they can process a request?). The way you set it up now you need to invoke the class somehow to trigger the static constructor, too indirect.
- If detecting whether or not a FunctionProvider supports a given request is trivial consider making it part of configuration. If *this* is in the request map it to *that* FunctionProvider. This would seperate concerns a bit better. If the detection is complicated consider doing it in seperate classes from the FunctionProvider.
- By configuring a delegate/function pointer you can possibly prevent from needing a FunctionProvider altogether (not sure if/how Java supports delegates).

Comment: I have no way of knowing what `FunctionProvider`s are present at run time though - so bootstrapping with a list of them, populating a request map etc. are impossible.

Comment: In that case you can perhaps create an external file that contains the mapping using class names? Instantiate a class instance by using the string in the mapping/config file..

Comment: Karl - listing all loaded classes, or finding all subclasses of a given class, is not a simple problem in Java. If you genuinely don't know what FunctionProvider classes are present in the system, you might have problems.